# Insert a page like a customizable component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

In my app im using two layouts, one for mobile and other for browser. On a particular page im using tabs to navigate between two pages, but in browser environment i would like the two pages to appear together in two columns.
For this i tried something like this:

```
<ion-tabs *ngIf="deviceCtrl.isMobile;else desktop">
        <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Pageone" tabIcon="contacts"></ion-tab>
        <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Pagetwo" tabIcon="list"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
<ng-template #desktop>
        <page-one></page-one>
        <page-two></page-two>
</ng-template>
```

In mobile its works fine, but in the browser appear blank page without error message.

I expected that behavior works like customizable components, this dont work because the pages has @IonicPage()? How can i make it work like a component ir browser or like a Ionic page in mobile?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it show it correctly in browser if you remove the tabs and *ngIf and only keep ng-template?

Comment: After doing some tests I discovered that the problem is exactly what you said. The real problem is to insert a Ionic Page on a another page, which usually occurs in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two components, you should be able to just show them without ng-template:

```
    <page-one></page-one>
    <page-two></page-two>
```

Also, you may wanna check SplitPane.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/split-pane/SplitPane/